# HOWTO: SharePoint 2007 resource file access form webapp App_GlobalResources in workflows?

Tags: 2007

How to get resources from webapplications **App_GlobalResources** directory in workflows ?

Is it only way to put resources in to 12/Resources directory and get them with above method?

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString()
```

Thank you in advance

SAV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my experience that resources in App_GlobalResources can not always be accessed as it relies on the HttpContext being present, which is not always the case, e.g. after a 'wait for' or 'wait until' workflow action.

Comment: Yeas you are right! Nevertheless I have to use GetLocalizedString() to get resources from 12 hive in a workflow that works perfect...

Comment: I don't understand, did I answer your question or do you still have an issue?

Comment: You did answer... from workflow context we cant use resources from App_Global... thx sav